# unicode-math, \mathscr and \mathcal

Tags: unicode-math

In the latest version of `unicode-math` documentation (`2018/01/07 v0.8j`), it seems to me that `\mathcal` and `\mathscr` do not work as expected. See below a screenshot of page 15 of the documentation (note that the "standard" math font is used, no calligraphic or script version).

[image]

I guess it is a bug. Is there a workaround / fix?

Comment: If that's in the documentation, maybe that what's expected by definition?  That is, how else to know what's expected? Maybe expecting that is the bug?

Comment: I guess it's just a flaw in the documentation, because I get [this picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehvIC.png) that's the expected output.

Comment: Correction: if I load XITS Math with `StylisticSet=1` for `range={cal,bfcal}`, `\mathcal` doesn't work, whereas `\mathscr` does.

Comment: See https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/431

Comment: @egreg You're right. I should have checked. So I guess we must wait for a fix. Do you think I should clode my question?

Comment: @cjorssen I've now fixed the bug. Given the question is of relevance for the next day or so until the next version is released, may as well keep it open.

Comment: See https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/commit/fe711319bf07052358d0a6e87a2991bc34cd55e7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug and the fix will make it to CTAN in the next couple of days.
If you need a quick fix for your own documents, find the following snippet in `unicode-math-xetex.sty` and `unicode-math-luatex.sty`:

```
          }

        \cs_set_eq:NN \__um_set_mathalphabet_char:nnn \__um_mathmap_parse:nnn
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__um_map_char_single:nn \__um_map_char_parse:nn
        \__um_mathalph_map:
```

and replace it with:

```
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__um_set_mathalphabet_char:nnn \__um_mathmap_parse:nnn
        \cs_set_eq:NN \__um_map_char_single:nn \__um_map_char_parse:nn
        \__um_mathalph_map:

          }
```

(I.e., just move the closing brace down.)
Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks for this quick fix! I won't need to ask to delay my deadline project `:-)`.